# Python - создание списка значений, полученных через API

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
class PythonUtilities(object):
    _public_methods_ = ['func_base']

    _reg_clsid_ = "{.......................}"
    _reg_desc_ = ""
    _reg_progid_ = ""
    _readonly_attrs_ = ['']

    _public_attrs_ = ['NDepVar', 'ArrayLen', 'ProbArray',
                      'X_cond1', 'X_cond2', 'X_cond3', 'X_cond4',
                      'X_cond5', 'X_cond6', 'Log']

    Log = ""

    def func_base(self, InList, coef0, coef1, coef2):
        self.revision = "version 1"
        OutList = []

        InList = list(InList)

        if len(InList) == 0:
            return OutList
        OutList = InList[:]
        for index in range(0, len(InList)):
            OutList.append(
                coef0 * InList[index] + coef1 * InList[index - 1] + coef2 * InList[index - 2])
        OutList.append(0)
        if OutList is None:
            return
        else:
            return OutList
```

Comment: Что именно значит "не получается"?

Comment: func_out - это функция или метод?

Comment: Вам нужно прочитать какой-нибудь учебник. Если функция объявлена в пространстве имён класса, то она либо должна иметь `self` и вызываться на объекте этого класса, либо должна быть помечена как статическая и вызываться на самом классе. Если вам нужна обычная функция, объявляйте её вне класса.

Comment: "Если функция объявлена в пространстве имён класса, то она либо должна иметь self и вызываться на объекте этого класса," Учебники читаю, но если не могу найти практическое решение, то обращаюсь за помощью... Функция объявлена в пространстве имен класса. Вызвать на объекте этого класса  - что я и пытаюсь....

Comment: Кто-нибудь может практически показать, как решить мой вопрос? В библиотеку обязательно схожу,

Comment: Ну судя по всему вам вообще не нужно вручную из этого модуля вызывать func_base. Вы регистрируете com сервер, дальше подключаетесь к нему com клиентом.

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [mre]

Answer (score 3):

1. Нужно привести в порядок отступы внутри класса
2. Насколько я понимаю, `func_out` - отдельная функция, нужно убрать отступы перед ней, чтобы она была не внутри класса `PythonUtilities`
3. `func_base` - метод, его нужно вызывать от объекта `PythonUtilities`, который нужно сначала создать
4. При вызове `func_base` нужно передать 4 параметра - входной список (`InList`) и 3 коэффициента.

```
class PythonUtilities(object):
    _public_methods_=['func_base']

    def func_base(self,InList,coef0,coef1,coef2):
        self.revision="version 1"
        OutList=[]
            
        ...
        
        return OutList


def func_out(OutList):
    print(OutList)


func_out(PythonUtilities().func_base([],0,0,0))
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112898/discussion-on-answer-by-insolor-python----).